# Threshold on GCP API for one IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, threshold

We are planning to use extensively Google APIs to transcribe audio in text from a single computer (about 10.000 requests approximately at the same time).

Except quota issues, are you aware of any other limitations on APIs calls coming from the same address ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [following article](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content), you can see that there are some restrictions and limits when it comes to the speech-to-text api.

Other than the ones mentioned in the article, there are no restrictions or limits. When making a call to an API, it depends on the amount of requests, not where it comes from. The API does not care if the requests come from one or multiples addresses. As long as the requests do not go over the Quota that the API can handle, it will be okay.